# Is there a way in pytest to generate test report from custom file for non-python test cases?

Tags: pytest

**Background**

Trigger legacy non-python testcases from pytest. Since these testcases are categorized as testsuites, from pytest perspective we'll be doing an ssh on a remote machine and trigger a testsuite. *So from pytest's point of view it is a single testcase, but actually it would be a bunch executing on remote machine.*

**Requirement**

The testsuite will generate a testreport which we'll SCP back to the pytest machine. I wish to parse the testreport and report the PASS/FAIL for each testcase from pytest

I have been looking into [example](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/nonpython.html) but still can't get my head around on how would I trigger the test case with SSH and parse the testreport(XML/JSON) and generate pytest report

Any suggestions ?

**Update**:

I have been able to parse the `yaml` file to generate the terminal report(`pytest_terminal_summary`) for my testcases. But I would like that pytest also reports the number of testcases failed/passed.

Comment: FYI: link to example file is broken

Comment: Must have changed. It was working earlier. Updated now

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `pytest test.py -v --junitxml="result.xml"`

You can also generate html result using `pytest file.py -sv --html report.html`

Comment: My requirement is not generate reports via `pytest`. Instead I wish `pytest` to interpret and report PASS/FAIL from the results file generated by the legacy testsuites